# undefined method `flush_errors' for #<ImageUploader:0x007f98fc4ef808>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-upload

I used paperclip gem in my project. It is working fine on local and on staging but on production it is giving me following error:

"**undefined method `flush_errors' for #ImageUploader:0x007f98fc4ef808>**" while creating account(Registartion).
To created an account user needs to fill following information :
  -firstname
  -lastname
  -email ID
  -location
  -password

On successful registration user is redirected to user timeline page from this page user can set his/her profile image.

User table columns:
["id", "oauth_token", "email", "firstname", "lastname", "location", "gender", "phone", "hashed_password", "salt", "f
acebook_id", "isFacebookUser", "confirm_token", "email_confirmed", "filename", "userinfo", "created_at", "updated_at", "
image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "image"]

User params function from users_controller :

```
def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:salt,:hashed_password,:password, :firstname,:lastname ,:phone,:gender ,:email,:location,:filename,:content_type,:data,:image,:userinfo, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
end
```

user.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "follower_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
has_many :followeds, through: :active_relationships
has_many :posts

before_create :confirmation_token

belongs_to :gallery
attr_accessor :password, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_h, :crop_w, :password_confirmation
after_update :reprocess_image, :if => :cropping?
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

def cropping?
  !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
end

def image_geometry
  img = Magick::Image::read(self.image.current_path).first
  @geometry = {:width => img.columns, :height => img.rows }
end


private
   def reprocess_image
     self.image.recreate_versions!
   end
```

[image]

Comment: Show your `user` model code

Comment: I added user model code.

Comment: Hey the above code tells that, you are using `carrierwave`. But you mentioned `paperclip` on comment

Comment: Here the reference link for [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Comment: Also make sure that your `Gemfile` should contains `gem "carrierwave"` and proceed with `bundle install`

Comment: Yes, It is already included.

Comment: But still it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87976/discussion-between-prashant4020-and-puja).